# Hilbert modular form as a representation of Hecke algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms, galois-representations

I am reading [some notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/modseminar/pdf/L18.pdf) by Snowden and I don't understand a sentence.

> Clearly, if we have an appropriate $R = T$
>   theorem then we get a modularity lifting theorem, as $\rho$ defines a homomorphism $R \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ and thus (by
>   $R = T$), a homomorphism $T \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$, which is the same as a modular form.

Why is this true?

Comment: What part you don't understand? Why a homomorphism $T \to \overline{\mathbb Q}_p$ is the same as a modular form?